# Google Sheets - Function Works Stand Alone Not When in FormulaArray

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have vacation start and stop dates for an array of names. I am looking to see if a given date falls between and return "Vacation" if yes, "Active" if not.

The function works if it is stand along i.e. just for H39 with no array, however when I put it into the array formula it always returns "Active"

=arrayformula(if(AND('VacationDay!$N$2>=H39:H,'VacationDay!$N$2<=I39:I,OR(E39:E="Vacation",E39:E="Skip")),"Vacation","Active"))

Thank you,

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works

```
=arrayformula(if(('VacationDay!$N$2>=H39:H)*('VacationDay!$N$2<=I39:I)*((E39:E="Vacation")+(E39:E="Skip")),"Vacation","Active"))
```

AND and OR don't work in an arrayformula. They need to be replace with * (AND) and + (OR). Hope this helps.